# Violation nonlinear constraints fmincon interior-point Matlab

Tags: matlab, optimization

I am trying to impose two nonlinear constraints with `fmincon (interior-point)` in Matlab:

```
sqrt(w*S*w') <= sigmaTgt/sqrt(260)
sqrt(w*S*w') >= sigmaTgt/sqrt(260)-0.02/sqrt(260)
```

I tried the following:

```
function [c,ceq] = in_nonlconstr(w, S)

    c(1) = sqrt(w*S*w') - tgtVolAnn/sqrt(260);
    c(2) = - sqrt(w*S*w') + ( tgtVolAnn/sqrt(260) - 0.02/sqrt(260) );
    ceq = [];

end
```

but after the optimization I keep getting that `sqrt(w*S*w')` satisfies `c(1)` but not `c(2)`, despite an `exitflag` of 1 and the solver having converged.

Am I writing it correctly or is there smth wrong with my solver?

---

Message from `output.message`:

> Local minimum found that satisfies the constraints.
>
> Optimization completed because the objective function is
>   non-decreasing in  feasible directions, to within the default value of
>   the optimality tolerance, and constraints are satisfied to within the
>   default value of the constraint tolerance.
>
> Stopping criteria details:
>
> Optimization completed: The relative first-order optimality measure,
>   9.821943e-07, is less than options.OptimalityTolerance = 1.000000e-06, and the relative maximum constraint violation, 0.000000e+00, is less
>   than options.ConstraintTolerance = 1.000000e-06.
>
> Optimization Metric                                            Options
>   relative first-order optimality =   9.82e-07       OptimalityTolerance
>   =   1e-06 (default) relative max(constraint violation) =   0.00e+00    ConstraintTolerance =   1e-06 (default)

Comment: Yes because I am putting *-1 to transform from >= to <=. How would you have done it?

Comment: can you run this for me?  options = optimset('fmincon') and post the variables inside options?  Then I can give you a solution rather quickly even though I don't have the Optimization Toolbox.

Answer (score 1):

Give this a shot:

```
options = optimset('OptimalityTolerance', 1e-20, 'ConstraintTolerance', 1e-20); 
% this may need to be instead started with the function name, depends on your MATLAB version
options = optimset('fmincon','OptimalityTolerance', 1e-20, 'ConstraintTolerance', 1e-20);
fmincon(....., options) % i.e. what you already are passing to fmincon but adding additional tolerances
```

Let me know if that solves your problem.  If not my variable names are probably wrong, I'd need you to run `options=optimset('fmincon')` and post the variable names inside `options` to set the tolerances.  The other option you have is to change your algorithm - MATHWORKS says `sqp` is usually better than the method you're using:

```
options = optimset('fmincon','Algorithm','sqp','TolConSQP',1e-20) % other choices are 'active-set' or 'trust-region-reflective' and don't have the `TolConSQP` tolerance parameter, which you may not need at all anyhow
```

You of course can use a lower tolerance if it works for your application - it seems 1e-20 is the largest for any of the algorithms.
See here for documentation: http://www.mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/fmincon.html#inputarg_options